# Formulas Not Copying Down When Inserting a New Row in Table

Tags: excel

I have a table that has like 15 rows. When I first started the table, I was only using 3 formulas in the row. Now on row 15, I have added 2 more formulas, so there are 5 cells in the row with formulas. However, when I hit tab to start a new row, it only brings down the original 3 formulas, not the new 2 formulas.

I have gone into Options and turned on "Fill formulas in tables to create calculated columns", but it still doesn't work.

[image: Screenshot of table]

The highlighted cells are the cells that have should have the formulas from the above row. It brings down some formulas but not all.

All the other similar questions seem to have VB in them. I am not using VB or know how to use it.

This is happening on multiple spreadsheets and I am clueless what to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A calculated column is one where all the rows have the formula. That doesn't look like the case with your data (you have rows with numeric values, not formulas).

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-calculated-columns-in-a-table-in-excel-for-the-web-f048e0fe-120f-4717-9f07-50a0b1410263

Comment: So there is no way to make a new formula in a cell if there is text above in the column?

Comment: You can't make a calculated column that includes rows with text, but you may be able to use VBA.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and for me the solution was the following:
The new formulas I added later were NOT starting from the first cell above the title, but midway from the row where I started adding them.
When I canceled all the values in the column where the formulas didn't copy down and inserted the formula in the first row under the title, the new formulas copied down without problem and were also added automatically in new rows.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and discovered that when I had a formula that referenced cell locations (e.g., `=R61/L61`), the formula wouldn't copy down when I added a new row. When I changed it to reference the column headers (e.g., `=[@[Net dividends received]]/[@[Book Value]]`), the formulas copied to new rows.

Answer (score 0):

Any formula that references cells directly (`R61/L61`) is a relative reference that will change sequentially if you try to copy it down a column, and will also prevent it from auto-populating a new row in a table.

If you change those cell references to *absolute references*, (`$R$61/$L$61`), then it will automatically calculate the column with each succeeding row.

> **NOTE:** the `$` before the column locks the reference to that column, and the `$` before the row locks the reference to the row. You can use a lock on just one or the other if you choose, or both.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Nathaniel, and thank you for your contribution. I've edited your answer to improve the formatting using markdown. Please review my edit so that you can use similar formatting techniques on future contributions to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having a similar problem.

I want to have a table to record simple banking transactions.
There are 5 columns but only 3 are relevant to this question.
[@withdrawal], [@deposit], [@balance]  in my table balance is column E.

So the balance computation for row 5 is:

```
=E4-[@withdrawal]+[@deposit]
```

I can extend this formula by dragging or copying it but it is not propagated into new rows when the table is extended.
With the exception that if I extend the table by dragging the balance formula down that works.

I suspect that the reason that this formula cannot automatically propagate is that it requires a different formula in the first row. Actually the first row needs to have a number in the [@Balance] field.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31196449)